# Rotating a picture causes rotation of other pictures in a loop g2d.rotate

Tags: java, swing, rotation, graphics2d, java-2d

I'm trying to make a game like Tank Trouble.

The problem is that when I'm trying to rotate and draw a tank picture, all other tanks pictures will be rotated.

Here is my code:

```
// draw tanks
ArrayList<Tank> tanks = new ArrayList<>();
tanks.addAll(TankTroubleMap.getAITanks());
tanks.addAll(TankTroubleMap.getUserTanks());
for (Tank tankToDraw : tanks) {
    g2d.rotate(-Math.toRadians(tankToDraw.getAngle())
            , tankToDraw.getCenterPointOfTank().getXCoordinate()
            , tankToDraw.getCenterPointOfTank().getYCoordinate());
    g2d.drawImage(tankToDraw.getTankImage()
            , (int) tankToDraw.getCenterPointOfTank().getXCoordinate() - Constants.TANK_SIZE / 2
            , (int) tankToDraw.getCenterPointOfTank().getYCoordinate() - Constants.TANK_SIZE / 2
            , Constants.TANK_SIZE, Constants.TANK_SIZE, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to counter-rotate graphics back once you've drawn the image you wanted to rotate. Otherwise the same rotation will be applied to everything painted past the point you applied the rotation at.

So in your case:

```java
    for (Tank tankToDraw : tanks) {
        g2d.rotate(-Math.toRadians(tankToDraw.getAngle())
                , tankToDraw.getCenterPointOfTank().getXCoordinate()
                , tankToDraw.getCenterPointOfTank().getYCoordinate());
        g2d.drawImage(tankToDraw.getTankImage()
                , (int) tankToDraw.getCenterPointOfTank().getXCoordinate() - Constants.TANK_SIZE / 2
                , (int) tankToDraw.getCenterPointOfTank().getYCoordinate() - Constants.TANK_SIZE / 2
                , Constants.TANK_SIZE, Constants.TANK_SIZE, null);
        g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(tankToDraw.getAngle())
                , tankToDraw.getCenterPointOfTank().getXCoordinate()
                , tankToDraw.getCenterPointOfTank().getYCoordinate());
    }
```

Any transformations (in this case - rotation) you apply to graphics are preserved for all future operations you perform on that graphics instance, including further transformations. You have to remember that when working with graphics.

Comment: Instead of an expensive counter-clockwise rotation that may introduce rounding errors, consider either, creating a sub-graphics via `create()` that does not affect the original graphics or using `getTransform()` before rotating and `setTransform​(…)` to restore the old value afterwards. If the transformation is the only changed property, I’d use the latter. Note that you can do the `getTransform()` once before the loop here.

Comment: That is a good suggestion! Although you should be careful with applying custom transform because it will overwrite all previous transformations done to graphics which can cause some unintended effects. Creating copy of graphics instance is certainly the safer way to go around.

Comment: Yes, `setTransform​(…)` should be used with care. [Its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setTransform(java.awt.geom.AffineTransform)) names this specific use case of restoring the old transformation as the intended use case. It should not be used for other purposes.